# Reference a uiviewtablecontroller from uiviewcontroller

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiviewcontroller

I have a property called currentViewController that either points to a UIViewController or UITableViewController depending on what segment in a UISegmentedControl is active.

If the currentViewController happens to point to UITableViewController, I can change the UITableView into editing mode by

```
[self.currentViewController setEditing:YES animated:YES];
```

However, I now want to run reloadData on the tableView. I tried this,
`[self.currentViewController reloadData];`

and it failed.

Any ideas on how can I reloadData on the tableView.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`[self.currentViewController setEditing:YES animated:YES];` Works well because it's defined for both UIViewController ([link](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIViewController/setEditing:animated:)) and UITableViewController (via subclassing UIViewController). You really want to be calling `reloadData` on the tableView, not on either of the ViewControllers.

Try something like:

```
  if([self.currentViewController isKindOfClass:[UITableViewController class]]){
    UITableViewController *tableVC = (UITableViewController *)self.currentViewController;
    [tableVC.tableView reloadData];
  }
```